# access to field not possible, although public and defined in constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hi I am trying to reference between forms. I got his Code...

```
main.cs

namespace GDISClient
{
    public class Program : ApplicationContext
    {
        public Form_main mainForm = null;

        public static int startvar = 0;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var splash = new Splashscreen(new Form_main());
            Application.Run(splash);
        }
        public Program(Form_main mainForm)
        {
            this.mainForm = mainForm;

        }
    }
}
```

and

```
splashcreen (form)

namespace GDISClient
{
    public partial class Splashscreen : Form
    {
        public Form_main mainForm;

        public Splashscreen(Form_main mainForm)
        {
            this.mainForm = mainForm;
        }

        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private pwencode encoder = new pwencode();
        private dbcon mysqlcon = new dbcon(mainForm); // <- this here wont work because he can not reference to that, why ?
    }
}
```

I tried to reference `new dbcon(mainForm)` and this `mainform` is not accessible, but it is public and i moved that to the constructor, what should i do ?

Comment: What is `dbcon`?

Comment: dbcon is a class, who Needs the mainForm got referenced...

Comment: Show that class also?

Comment: ill updated my post, so its shown

Comment: Does it work if it is public? private dbcon mysqlcon = new dbcon(mainForm);

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a console application to try to start a forms application? Why not windows forms application in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of your question. The problem is here:

```
public Form_main mainForm;  // Declared but not Initialized 
private dbcon mysqlcon = new dbcon(mainForm);  // using a variable that has not been initialized
```

**Solution:**
Replace the `constructor` of `Splashscreen` by given `constructor`:

```
public Splashscreen(Form_main mainForm)
{
    this.mainForm = mainForm;
    private dbcon mysqlcon = new dbcon(mainForm);
}
```

Comment: **NOTE:** New users must take this to account, that if they find the answer correct and it resolves their issue, then _kindly_ mark that as **answer**. That's how things work here . Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `mainForm` is not initialized yet. Create `dbcon` in constructor and pass reference to `mainForm` there.